# Access Protected Pages in JSF

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, navigation

I have found a way to protect direct access fofr my `.xhtml` Pages by having this security Constraint in my web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
        <display-name>Restrict raw XHTML Documents</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint />
    </security-constraint>
```

however this seems to restrict My welcome file Listing in the web.xml which I have like this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

I also cannot Seem to access My Pages from beans in this method:

```
public void getBreakEvenProductPage(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
       FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest origRequest = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        String contextPath = origRequest.getContextPath();
        try {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                    .redirect(contextPath + "/faces/BreakEvenProfProduct.xhtml");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.debug(Level.FATAL, e);
        }
    }
```

xhtml for above method:

```
<p:menuitem value="Break Even Rate Profit report" 
action="#{Navigation.getBreakEvenProductPage(event)}"/>
```

My problem is that I have come up with another Problem by trying to address a problem. How Can I access these pages with the security constraint in place??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to change 

`<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>`

to
`<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.jsf</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>`
And make sure you have following lines in your web.xml
`<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`